# Get a table that can change data directly

Tags: php, html

I want to get the data to create a table that can edit,that means the data that i get in database can be shown in input type box and the user can change it directly in the table.

Here is my code: in the code i get the name , DOB(date of born) and tel. I want these data
show in text boxes in a way that allows the direct edition of these data.

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");
  mysql_select_db("school2");
  $sql = "Select * from student";
  $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);

  echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=10>";
  echo "<tr><th>SID</th><th>Name</th><th>DOB</th><th>Tel</th></tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
    echo "<tr>
            <td>$row[0]</td>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td>$row[3]</td>
          </tr>";

  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: so whats the problem.....?? any errors....or output??

Comment: the code above just show out ,it can't edit . i want the data show in a text boxs ,i can edit these data and change it directly.

Comment: Try <input type=text value='{$row[0]}'>

Comment: You'll need [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your only target is text boxes, changes this :

```
 echo "<tr>
            <td>$row[0]</td>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td>$row[3]</td>
          </tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<tr>
        <td><input type=text id='row0' name='row0' value='$row[0]' /></td>
        <td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='$row[1]' /></td>
        <td><input type=text id='row2' name='row2' value='$row[2]' /></td>
        <td><input type=text id='row3' name='row3' value='$row[3]' /></td>
     </tr>";
```

after this, you'll need a <kbd>Submit / Update</kbd> button, which onClick, fetches these values from the above table and updates the corresponding record in the Database